# Find an ip address with subnetmask in a file

Tags: bash

I have been working in this script for some days already. First I was asked to match only the ip address and that is what I did, now I was asked to match the ip address with the subnet mask(the short version). For instance, 192.168.2.13/21. This script works just fine to match the ip address without the subnet mask. QUESTION: How can I modify this script to match an ip address with the subnet(/21) mask but also return the same ip address with other subnet mask that I didn't mention. For example, if I input 192.168.2.13/21 it will also return if found 192.168.2.13/19 and/or 192.168.2.13/22, etc. This is what I have done. Thank you

```
 #!/bin/bash

 valid_ip(){
    local stat=1
    ip="$1"
    if [[ $ip =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
       OIFS=$IFS
       IFS='.'
       a=($ip)
       IFS=$OIFS
  [[ ${a[0]} -le 255 && ${a[1]} -le 255 && ${a[2]} -le 255 && ${a[3]} -le 255 ]]
   stat=$?

 fi
 return $stat
 }

 red='\e[0;31m'
 nc='\e[0m'
 blue='\e[0;34m'
 yellow='\e[1;33m'
 echo -e "${red}Type 0 to quit${nc}"
 while true; do
 echo -e "${yellow}Enter an IP address: ${nc}\c"
 read ip

 if [ $ip == 0 ]; then
    echo "Good Bye!!"
    break;
   elif valid_ip $ip; then
       if egrep $ip ips; then
          echo $ip >> advertised
          echo $ip "is been advertised"
         else
          echo $ip >> Notadvertised
          echo $ip "is not been adversited"
       fi
   else
     echo "Not valid. Please re-enter IP address"
 fi

 done
```

Comment: Why not use `ipcalc` to validate IP addresses? It is in the initscripts package and you probably have it installed. You can then grep for `${ip}/{,1}` regardless of the mask and `/` being optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your script using `ipcalc` and `grep`ping for any IPAddress in and outside of the requested mask.

```
#!/bin/bash

red='\e[0;31m'
nc='\e[0m'
blue='\e[0;34m'
yellow='\e[1;33m'
echo -e "${red}Type 0 to quit${nc}"
while true; do
echo -e "${yellow}Enter an IP address: ${nc}\c"
read ip

if [ $ip == 0 ]; then
   echo "Good Bye!!"
   break;
  elif ipcalc -sc $ip; then
      if egrep "$ip/{,1}" ips; then
         egrep "$ip/{,1}" ips >> advertised
         echo $(egrep "$ip/{,1}" ips) "is been advertised"
        else
         egrep "$ip{,1}" ips >> Notadvertised
         echo $(egrep "$ip/{,1}" ips) "is not been adversited"
      fi
  else
    echo "Not valid. Please re-enter IP address"
fi

done
```